# Basis for polynomial subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{K}[x]_{\leq{n}}$ be the k-vector space for all the single variable polynomials $f(x)$ with $deg(f(x)) \leq n$, and $A=\{f(x) ∈ \mathbb{K}[x]_{\leq n}, x^2 + 1 | f(x)\}$ a linear subspace of $\mathbb{K}[x]_{\leq{n}}$. Find a basis for A.

I thought of taking a polynomial  $a(x) = a_0+a_1\cdot x+a_2\cdot x^2 + \dots a_m \cdot x^m , m\leq n$ and finguring out what conidtions need to apply in order $x^2 + 1 | a(x)$ by dividing them, but it seems like a lot of unnecessary work.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) \in \mathbb{K}[x]$ and $x^2+1|f$, then $\frac{f}{x^2+1} \in \mathbb{K}[x]$ as well. This polynomial is now an arbitrary polynomial of degree $\leq n-2$. So you can take a basis of $\mathbb{K}[x]_{\leq n-2}$, say the standard basis, and multiply by $x^2+1$. Then the first basis element is $(x^2+1)\cdot 1=x^2+1$, the second is $(x^2+1)\cdot x=x^3+x$, etc.